# webpack-dev-server@2.5.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 but none is installed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I apologize if this has been asked before, I can't find it. I'm a beginner and I've been trying to set up webpack so I can start learning react. After following a tutorial on youtube, I've installed react with

```
npm install --save react react-dom
```

And also tried enabling ES6 and JSX with

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-react
npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

And while trying to run dev, I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! webpack-starter@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-starter@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is my webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    stats: "errors-only",
    open: true,
    openPage: ''
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.scss$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']})},
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Project Demo',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: false // For minifying HTML to save on space
      },
      hash: false, // Name of app.bundle.js is changing to see if we're uploading the latest files
      template: './src/index.html', // Load a custom template (ejs by default see the FAQ for details)
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("app.css"),
  ]
}
```

I've also made .babelrc inside src folder. It contains this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

While installing all those above, the only warning I got was

> npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.5.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

But if I understand correctly, it's not an error, just a warning. Meaning, everything should still work. Am I wrong?

Can someone please let me know what is happening? How can I fix this? 
Thank you!

*EDIT:* Here is my package.json too:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Webpack project starter",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "prod": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "Name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-webpack": "^6.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: Did you install webpack?

Comment: @fshock Yes, I just ran 'npm view webpack version' and it's telling me I have version 3.8.1 installed.

Comment: add `loader: "babel-loader"` inside your loaders as currently i can't see any `babel-loader`

Comment: `npm view webpack version` will only show the latest webpack that is available to download from the registry. It will not show the installed version.  If you want to verify check for the entry of webpack in your package.json` You need to install webpack like `npm install --save-dev webpack`

Comment: instead of `npm view webpack version` try running `webpack -v` locally

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Didn't know that. But I did install webpack, I know that much. I ran it again now though, just in case, and it's still giving me exact same errors when I run dev. In package.json it says "webpack": "^3.8.1".

Comment: @Aaqib That didn't work either. But yeah. not sure what else I could try. Should I just uninstall all and reinstall it again? It keeps giving me same errors over and over again.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

`webpack-dev-server 2.5.0` isn't compatible with `webpack v3` or above and hence you need to upgrade your webpack-dev-server to `2.5.1` which fixed this issue. See this **[github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/961)**

You can do this by changing the version in `package.json` to `2.5.1` and running `npm install`

or

You can `uninstall` and `reinstall` it

```
npm uninstall webpack-dev-server --save-dev
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

Comment: Tried both approaches. But it still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Can you check the version of webpack-dev-server in package.json now. Also what error do you get now

Comment: When I change the version in package.json to 2.5.1 and run npm install, that's the version I get. When I uninstall and install again, I get "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4" in the package.json. The error messages, however, don't change at all, in either versions.

Comment: So the error message still tells you v2.5.0, can you should your package.json file please

Comment: Oh you mean when I try to run react or babel installation? No, it doesn't give me a warning anymore. But the issue are errors I get when I try to run dev, which are the errors I listed in my question.

Comment: I've added my package.json file to the question, too.

Comment: Is any other process running on port 8080

Comment: I just ran 'netstat -an | find ":8080"' and it shows nothing, so I guess it's free.